# Onsen UI + Angular 5+ and @angular/router

Tags: angular, onsen-ui2

I am wondering if anyone has got Onsen UI for angular 5+ working with the default angular router? I have Onsen UI installed and working. I am able to move
between pages using the [page] attribute but have had no luck getting routes/router-outlets working. When I remove [page] from the html, i get the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: this._content._show is not a function
```

Here is my html:

```
<ons-page>
  <ons-toolbar>
    <div class="center">{{title}}</div>
    <div class="left">
      <ons-toolbar-button>
        <ons-icon icon="ion-navicon, material:md-menu"></ons-icon>
      </ons-toolbar-button>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      <ons-toolbar-button>
        <ons-icon icon="ellipsis-v, material:md-menu"></ons-icon>
      </ons-toolbar-button>
    </div>
  </ons-toolbar>


  <ons-splitter #splitter>
      <ons-splitter-side side="left" width="220px" collapse swipeable>
        <sidebar></sidebar>
      </ons-splitter-side>

      <ons-splitter-content>
          <div class="content">
              <router-outlet></router-outlet>
            </div>
            <ons-tabbar>
              <div class="tabbar">
                <ons-tab label="Home" icon="ion-home" [routerLink]="['messages']" active></ons-tab>
                <ons-tab label="Messages" icon="envelope"></ons-tab>
                <ons-tab label="Events" icon="calendar"></ons-tab>
                <ons-tab label="Settings" icon="cog"></ons-tab>
              </div>
            </ons-tabbar>        
      </ons-splitter-content>
    </ons-splitter>
</ons-page>
```

and this is in my app.component.ts
messages.component.ts lives in a messages module that is imported into my app.module.ts along with it's own router module.

Thank you very much,
-Kevin